# C++ Attempting to use a vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, structure

Needing to use a vector for a Film object I have. Having errors thrown at me and unsure as to where things need to be moved to or if I'm naming things wrong. Probably something blatantly obvious.

Code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() 
{ 

    class Film 
    {
    public:
        Film();
        Film(string sl, string el);

    };

    cout << "Please enter first film:\n";
    string start_film;
    cin >> start_film;
    cout << "\nPlease enter a second film:\n";
    string end_film;
    cin >> end_film;
    cout << "\nPlease enter a date (format = dd/mm/yyyy):\n";
    string date;
    cin >> date;

    string name;
    name = "films.txt";
    ifstream ist(name.c_str());

    if (!ist)
        error("Cannot open output file " + name);

    vector<Film> temps; // create a vector to store the readings
    string film;
    string director;
    float rating;
    int year;
    int date;

    while (ist >> film >> director >> rating >> year >> date) 
    { // read
        // check
        temps.push_back(Film(film,director, rating, year, date)); // store
    }

    cout << "Start: " + start_film + " End: " + end_filmn + " Date: " + date + "\n";

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Any structure errors that can be pointed out or advice on where to go are much appreciated.

Warnings:

main::Flight::Flight local class member function does not have a body
Error: main::Flight::Flight : No overloaded function takes 5 arguments

Comment: "Having errors thrown at me" - then your _first_ step should be to throw them at us, so we don't have to invoke our psychic debugging skills.

Comment: Your code's riddled with mistakes... take `cin >> start_film;` for example - no error checking, and it will stop parsing at the first whitespace encountered; while many great movies have one word titles, it's a touch limiting.  You should use `if (getline(std::cin, start_film)) ...ok...; else ...error stuff...;` etc..  The Film class you list lacks a trailing ';', doesn't have a constructor for the number of arguments you're calling it for in the while loop etc....  Real code plus real error output please!

Comment: try to read the errors and figure out the problems. They have line numbers on them so it's not that hard. The errors are pretty close to plain english and usually tell you exactly what you need to do to fix them.